# How to Deploy Node.js Application

Tags: node.js

I have very basic knowledge about this web site technologies. I have started working on web servers . I started creating all the routes and when we save that code and run , then we can see all in only our systems . But how the real websites are working ? How people making their sites available to others ?? Please help me out

Answer (score 1):

Your question shows a sever lack of research, and yet, as you are a new contributor, here are some links to get you started with your research. Good luck, and ask specific questions here with code example if you run into deployment issues:

**On Platform as a Service (PaaS, free tier available on [Heroku](https://heroku.com)):**

https://medium.com/@grantspilsbury/build-and-deploy-a-node-express-server-to-heroku-in-10-steps-70c936ab15dc

**On Virtual Private Server (VPS, really cheap beginner plans on [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) and [Amazon LightSail](https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/pricing/)):**

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04

**On Amazon Aws (Free Tier Available for a limited time):**

https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/deploy-nodejs-web-app/